# How spring security authenticate the password(credential)?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I get this work but don't quite understand the process behind:

```
<!-- Authentication Manager -->
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <sec:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder">
```

And in `customUserDetailsService`:

```
@Component("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

............

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User '"+username+"' not found !");
        }

        return user;
    }

}
```

The user service basically just validate user with his or her name, but without validate it's password. But `password-encoder` does actually validate the password, so how Spring relate the encoder with `User` entity's password column? Where is the process to validate the user password?

### Question2

How to customize the password validation process to intercept the decrypted password?

Comment: where have you defined encoder bean? Post that as well

Comment: @dhamibirendra Thanks. Posted. But does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `User` class should have implemented [`UserDetails`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) that has the method `getPassword()`. As it's a Spring interface, they call this method when needed.

Comment: is there any way to intercept the decrypted password user enter to the application?

Comment: Try this: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials()`. It will return [user credentials](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html), that is the password.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer didn't work for me, I had to create a custom implementation of `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider`